# How to create limited search results using laravel and after if limit exsausted user would no longer able to search

Tags: laravel, search

I am building an laravel application. And the client wants to limit the search results. 
Like, suppose if users perform a search using the search form. the user would only be able to show the 10 results. after the 10th result user would need to buy the premium plan to search for more results.

Can anybody give me any idea about how to achieve the required result?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you simple can use the `take()` function on a model

> **skip / take**
>   To limit the number of results returned from the query, or to skip a given number of results in the query, you may use the `skip` and `take` methods:

```php
$items = Item::take(10)->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset